# Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.google.gms.google-services']

Tags: android, nsight, google-play-services

I'm trying to integrate firebase notifications, following firebase official tutorials for adding firebase to the android project and sending notifications to user segments.

My main difficulty is that all the tutorials and similar questions here are about Android Studio, but I'm using nsight tegra plugin for VS2010. No build.gradle files for project and app levels. There is a single tegra_nsight_build.gradle which is autogenerated somehow during the build process. nsight_tegra_build_overrides.gradle is automatically applied to it (two files are merged), it is located in the same folder as src, res, libs and assets. I put google-services.json in that folder as well.

My nsight_tegra_build_overrides.gradle looks like this (removed irrelevant lines):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
android
{
// ...
}
def googlePlayVersion = '9.0.2'

dependencies
{
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:' + googlePlayVersion
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:' + googlePlayVersion
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:' + googlePlayVersion
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:' + googlePlayVersion
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Buildtool version is 23.0.3. All necessary things in sdk manager are installed and updated to the latest version: [sdkmanager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yfuD.jpg)
Build fails with this error:

```
Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.google.gms.google-services']
```

Comment: see this : https://github.com/gonzaloaune/GCMPushPlugin/issues/2

Comment: It again tells about top-level build.gradle and project level build.gradle, which are not present in nsight tegra gradle build. Apart from that, all the necessary lines are already in nsight_tegra_build_overrides.gradle

Comment: If above is your top level build.gradle then note one thing : **you can not place your application dependencies here**

Comment: I would appreciate if someone can explain how does nsight_tegra_build_overrides.gradle in Nsight tegra correspond to top-level and project level gradle files in Android Studio, and where I can put dependencies, providing that there is no another gradle file in nsight tegra project. Or at least I have no idea where to put it.